# How to handle empty cell values in @tanstack/react-table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-table, tanstack

I am trying to find an optimal way to handle the empty cell values.
I have following column definition in which all the fields are optional except the name field:

```
const columnHelper = createColumnHelper<{
    name: string; 
    contact_person?: string; 
    phone_no?: string
}>();

export const countryColumns = () => [
    columnHelper.display({
        header: "S.N.",
        cell: ({ row }) => row.index + 1,
    }),
    columnHelper.accessor("name", {
        header: "Name",
    }),
    columnHelper.accessor("contact_person", {
        header: "Contact Person",
    }),
    columnHelper.accessor("phone_no", {
        header: "Phone Number",
    }),
    columnHelper.display({
        id: "actions",
        header: "Actions",
        cell: ({ row }) => (
      // Buttons
    ),
  }),
];
```

Here, contact_person and phone_no are optional fields. So, there might be cases where the contact_person and phone_no will be empty in the table. How do I handle it?

```
export const countryColumns = () => [
    columnHelper.display({
        header: "S.N.",
        cell: ({ row }) => row.index + 1,
    }),
    columnHelper.accessor("name", {
        header: "Name",
    }),
    columnHelper.accessor("contact_person", {
        header: "Contact Person",
        cell: info => info.getValue() ?? "---";
    }),
    columnHelper.accessor("phone_no", {
        header: "Phone Number",
        cell: info => info.getValue() ?? "---";
    }),
    columnHelper.display({
        id: "actions",
        header: "Actions",
        cell: ({ row }) => (
          // Buttons
        ),
    }),
];
```

Here, I need to check the condition in every optional field. Is this what I should do or there is another workaround?

Also, in the main table component, I tried doing something like this:

```
{row.getVisibleCells().map(cell => {
    return (
        <Td key={cell.id} pl={6}>
            {cell.getValue() ? flexRender(
            cell.column.columnDef.cell,
            cell.getContext(),
        ) : "---"}
        </Td>
  );
})}
```

However, this renders "---" in S.N. and "Actions" field too which are display columns. This only seems to work on accessor columns.